# 4x4 Rental in Northern Idaho

Tags: car-rentals, off-road, washington-state, idaho

I have some things to do in Northern Idaho that would require a day or two of driving on maintained-but-rough gravel roads and dirt driveways that I have my doubts about being able to get my compact car up.

As such, I am interested in the possibility of renting a 4x4 car in the Northern Idaho / Spokane area. I understand that normal mass market car rental vendors totally forbid any driving on unpaved roads in their terms and conditions. I would not be driving in wilderness or "rock hopping", and it would need to be a car, jeep, or truck, not a UTV or other recreational non-street-legal vehicle or a rental that only provides for recreational use.

What are my options? Are there any vendors in that area that provide this service? Attempts to search for this on the web mostly yield 1. adventure / recreational ATV rentals and 2. mainstream rental car companies that rent 4x4 SUVs but don't let you take them on a dirt road.

Comment: One option is simply a good carwash *nudge nudge wink wink*.  I've done that before driving a convertible around parts of AZ on some dirt roads.

Comment: When I last specifically rented a 4x4 (Tahoe) in the Pacific Northwest I don't recall the major rental car company saying anything about not taking it on a dirt road. Are you sure?